# How to select the students who have lowest test scores?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm learning SQL, and i'm trying to select all the students who has the lowest test score from below:

```
Given TABLE STUDENTS:
id     |    name     |    test_score
1      | John        |    89
2      | Marry       |    0
3      | Lena        |    100
4      | Peter       |    0
```

I want to select both Marry and Peter because they have the slowest test score. So far I have:

```
SELECT S.name, MIN(S.test_score) FROM STUDENTS S GROUP BY S.test_score;
```

Somehow, I get the result as below:

```
John  | 89
Marry | 0
Lena  | 100
```

I just want to print out only the name as :

```
Marry
Peter
```

Any hints how can I fix my query and what am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT name FROM tableName
WHERE test_score = (SELECT MIN(test_score) FROM tableName)
```

Comment: Thanks, hows about I want to select all users who have the least 2 scores? (In the example above, select all users whose test scores are 0 and 89)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    STUDENTS
HAVING 
    min(test_score)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.`name` FROM students s WHERE s.`test_score` IN(
SELECT MIN(test_score)
FROM students);
```

Answer (score 0):

Select top 1 ID, Name from STUDENTS order by test_score